# Google API calendar Promises

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

Im trying to insert a bunch of events with Google API Calendar and get the ids of the inserted events but im not able to get the response. I dont know what im doing wrong.

Here's what im doing:

```
GetEvents //fetchs the user events 
        .then(insertEvents)
        .catch(function (reason) {
            console.log(reason);
        });

function insertEvents(events) {

    var eventsToInsert = [];
    if (events.length) {
        for (evnt of events) {  //Here im creating an array of //"promises" that return the insert method of google API
            eventsToInsert.push(insertEvent(evnt.titulo, evnt.lugar, evnt.fechainicio, evnt.fechafin, evnt.tipologia,
                evnt.id))
        }
        console.log('Events ti insert');
        console.log(eventsToInsert);
        //And here im trying the return the resolved data by the all //promises, but it returns an empty array always
        Promise.all(eventsToInsert.map(function (eventToInsert) {
            return eventToInsert.execute(function (event) {
                console.log('event', event);
                 return event.id;
            });
        })).then(function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        });

    } 

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does `insertEvent` return? You've said you're "creating an array of promises" but later you use an `execute` method on those entries; promises don't have an `execute` method.

Comment: In the normal case, you wouldn't need two loops here. So we clearly need to know more about what you're doing and way.

Comment: What is `events`? If it's an array, your first loop using `for-in` is [not really correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476). You'd be better off with `var eventsToInsert = events.map(function(evnt) { return ... });`

Comment: I have a made mistake there and also in the `for loop` i have put the variable name wrong `eventsToInsert` instead of `events`. The `insertEvent` function returns a google api request object and to perform the insert it have to be executed.

Comment: Please use the "edit" link to fix any errors in your question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for your responses. What i want to do is insert n events in the google calendar and wait for its reponses and then  perform other actions. But im not able to wait or get the response because google methods are asynchronus.

Comment: I have been able to resolve this issue. Wrapping the google api `insert` method in a promise and resolve it in the `execute` method.